# MySQL NOW() Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have some software called phpVMS installed on my webserver and we are running software called SmartCARS which tracks a plane on a flight simulator and sends the data to the phpVMS software. At the end of the flight a PIREP is filed but for some reason I get an error with MySQL syntax. This is the error:

```
Time: 10.19.17 08:56:52

Backtrace: DB::write_debug > DB::query > PIREPData::fileReport > ACARSData::FilePIREP > smartCARS::filepirep
Query: INSERT INTO phpvms_pireps (`pilotid`, `code`, `flightnum`, `depicao`, `arricao`, `route`, `aircraft`, `load`, `flighttime`, `landingrate`, `submitdate`, `fuelused`, `source`, `log`, `distance`, `rawdata`, `flighttime_stamp`, `exported`, `modifieddate`, `accepted`, `expenselist`, `flighttype`) VALUES ('1', 'MCC', '124', 'EGKK', 'EGKK', '', '24', '140', '00.00', '5537', NOW(), '49', 'smartCARS', 'smartCARS version 2.1.31.0, 2017/10/19 UTC*[07:40:58] Preflight started, flying offline*[07:40:58] Flying FSLabs A320X CFM - Easyjet (new colors) (G-EZTA)*[07:56:02] Engine 1 is on*[07:56:02] Engine 2 is on*[07:56:21] Slew mode entered*[07:56:26] Pushing back with 4979 kg of fuel*[07:56:27] Taxiing to runway*[07:56:36] Taking off*[07:56:38] Climbing, pitch: 0, roll: level, 66 kts*[07:56:42] Touched down early at 5537 fpm, gear level: down, flaps: 0*[07:56:47] Landed in 558 ft, fuel: 4959 kg, weight: 61949 kg*[07:56:47] Taxiing to gate*[07:56:47] The flight may now be ended*[07:56:47] Taxi time was less than 15 seconds*[07:56:47] Arrived, flight duration: 00:00', '0', '', '00:00:00', '0', 'NOW()', '0', '0', 'P');
Error: (1292) - Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'modifieddate' at row 1
=====
```

I have also tried to change NOW() for DateAdd but I get the same error just with DateAdd replacing NOW() in the error log.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this error?

This is all the code I can find relevant to the query:

```
$pirepdata['exported'] = 0;
    $pirepdata['submitdate'] = 'NOW()';
    $pirepdata['modifieddate'] = 'NOW()';
    $pirepdata['accepted'] = PIREP_PENDING;
    $pirepdata['expenselist'] = '0';
    $pirepdata['flighttype'] = $sched->flighttype;

    # Do the insert based on the columns here
    $cols = array();
    $col_values = array();
    foreach ($pirepdata as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'submitdate') {
            $value = 'NOW()';
        } elseif ($key == 'comment') {
            continue;
        } else {
            $value = "'".DB::escape($value)."'";
        }

        $cols[] = "`{$key}`";        
        $col_values[] = $value;
    }

    $cols = implode(', ', $cols);
    $col_values = implode(', ', $col_values);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . TABLE_PREFIX . "pireps ({$cols}) VALUES ({$col_values});";

    DB::query($sql);
    $pirepid = DB::$insert_id;
```

I tried removing the single quote from the code but I get this error

```
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function now() in /var/www/fly/core/common/PIREPData.class.php on line 710
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/frame.php:0
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP   2. smartCARS::filepirep() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/frame.php:269
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP   3. ACARSData::FilePIREP() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/interface.php:745
[25-Oct-2017 09:02:27 Europe/London] PHP   4. PIREPData::fileReport() /var/www/fly/core/common/ACARSData.class.php:280
```

If I try to use the php date function I get this error

```
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Y' (T_STRING) in /var/www/fly/core/common/PIREPData.class.php on line 710
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP Stack trace:
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/frame.php:0
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP   2. smartCARS::filepirep() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/frame.php:269
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP   3. ACARSData::FilePIREP() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/interface.php:745
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP   4. spl_autoload_call() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/interface.php:280
[25-Oct-2017 09:04:51 Europe/London] PHP   5. codon_autoload() /var/www/fly/core/smartcars/interface.php:280
```

Comment: Remove single quote. It is `NOW()` not `'NOW()'`

Comment: I have added my code that is on the software

Comment: @siddiq would removing the single quote work with the setup that I have?

Comment: If using php date function is fine for you, then you can use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead of `NOW()`

Comment: Simply put `now()` is not a PHP function.

Comment: I have updated the post, I dont think using date works. For some reason though NOW() works for the submitdate field just not the modified date field

Comment: Instead of `if($key == 'submitdate') { $value = 'NOW()'; }` use `if($key == 'submitdate' || $key == 'modifieddate') { $value = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); }` . If still not works let know what data type you have used for both the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your program as-is you will find that the value in $sql is something like:

```
INSERT INTO wp_pireps (`exported`, `submitdate`, `modifieddate`, `accepted`, `expenselist`, `flighttype`) VALUES ('0', NOW(), 'NOW()', 'PIREP_PENDING', '0', '');
```

You will notice that the 'NOW()' value for modifieddate is quoted. To fix this all you need to do is change the first check in your foreach to :

```
if($key == 'submitdate' || $key == 'modifieddate')
```

Hope this helps.